# python threading and performance?

Tags: python, performance, multithreading

I had to do  heavy I/o bound operation, i.e Parsing large files and converting from one format to other format. Initially I used to do it serially, i.e parsing one after another..! Performance was very poor ( it used take 90+ seconds). So I decided to use threading to improve the performance. I created one thread for each file. ( 4 threads)

```
 for file in file_list:
            t=threading.Thread(target = self.convertfile,args = file)
            t.start()
            ts.append(t)
 for t in ts:
            t.join()
```

But for my astonishment, there is no performance improvement whatsoever. Now also it takes around 90+ seconds to complete the task. As this is I/o bound operation , I had expected to improve the performance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under the usual Python interpreter, threading will not allocate more CPU cores to your program because of the [global interpreter lock](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock) (aka. the GIL).

The [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module could help you out here. (Note that it was introduced in Python 2.6, but backports exist for Python 2.5.)

As MSalters says, if your program is I/O bound it's debatable whether this is useful. But it might be worth a shot :)

To achieve what you want using this module:

```
import multiprocessing

MAX_PARALLEL_TASKS = 8 # I have an Intel Core i7 :)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MAX_PARALLEL_TASKS)

pool.map_async(convertfile, filelist)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

**Important!** The function that you pass to `map_async` must be pickleable. In general, instance methods are NOT pickleable unless you engineering them to be so! Note that `convertfile` above is a function.

If you actually need to get results back from `convertfile`, there are ways to do that as well. The examples on the multiprocessing documentation page should clarify.

Comment: Thanks delty..But multiprocessing module has its own problems.
1) I have to refactor my code as I can't use instance methods..
2) I have an instance method which has many file handler..Those file handlers are closed in child processes which is not acceptable. So I need to open them again. Unfortunately I have no way to know them as these are passed during instantiation

Comment: It doesn't have to be the conversion function itself that is performed in a separate process. Is there any way you can do the instantiation part in separate processes? Eg. write a function or even a separate script that does a single instantiation and conversion; then write a "master script" that uses the multiprocessing module to run these functions. Separate scripts can be run using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. If there is a lot of shared data, then yes, that's where multiprocessing gets complicated. But there are a lot more tools in that module :)

Answer (score 2):

Threading allows the OS to allocate more CPU cores to your program. If it's I/O bound, that means that the speed was limited by the I/O susbsystem speed instead of the CPU speed. In those cases, allocating more CPU cores doesn't necessarily help - you're still waiting on the I/O subsystem.

Comment: But I believe thread switching happens when a thread is waiting for I/o subsyetm, isn't it? So I am doing the things parallel now which means I can expect some performance improvement ??

Comment: Threading in Python does not allocate more CPU cores to the program.

Comment: @kumar: As the response says, if you're I/O bound - your I/O is going as hard as it can - more CPU time or parallel processing isn't going to make the I/O finish any earlier.